# Hadoop program with Python - Use of generators to read files

Tags: python, hadoop, generator, yield

I am trying to understand how to write a Hadoop program using Python with this tutorial http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

This is mapper.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""A more advanced Mapper, using Python iterators and generators."""

import sys

def read_input(file):
    for line in file:
        # split the line into words
        yield line.split()

def main(separator='\t'):
    # input comes from STDIN (standard input)
    data = read_input(sys.stdin)
    for words in data:
        # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
        # what we output here will be the input for the
        # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
        #
        # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1
        for word in words:
            print '%s%s%d' % (word, separator, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't understand the use of `yield`. `read_input` generates one line at the time. However, `main` only calls `read_input` once, which corresponds to the first line of the file. How do the remaining lines get read as well?

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/236871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `main` calls `read_input` several times.

```
data = read_input(sys.stdin)
# Causes a generator to be assigned to data.
for words in data:
```

In every loop of the for loop, `data`, which is the generator returned by `read_input`, is called.  The output of `data` is assigned to `words`.

Basically, `for words in data` is shorthand for "call data and assign the output to words, then execute the loop block".

Comment: +1 Another way of thinking of it is `for words in read_input(sys.stdin)`, where `read_input` is a list that is created on the fly.

Comment: @mr2ert - indeed, agreed.